# File Manager won't display folder contents within same window after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, files, filemanager

I was using 12.04. When using the file manager it used to display a widget/icon in the shape of an inverted triangle along side folders that you could click to open a folder to display its contents within the same window. I just upgraded to 14.04 and that widget/icon is gone, requiring the folder to be opened in a new window.

The 12.04 version was very handy for moving and copying files within a single window.

Is there a way to get that widget/icon back? Do I have a faulty installation of the new "Files" in 14.04? and if so, how do I reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean for a display that looks like this

[image]

then go to the menu->edit->preferences->display and check the "navigate folders in a tree" checkbox

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks very much. I looked at preferences before I came here, but didn't understand that I needed to have that box checked since 12.04 was set up that way to begin with. Thanks again.

Comment: @user136484 - Your welcome - if the answer suffices, please check the accept button!

Comment: My page isn't showing an "accept" button????

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Folder View? There are 3 types of Folder Views in Nautilus:

[image]

[image]

- Icons (Ctrl+1)
- Lists (Ctrl+2)
- Compact (Ctrl+3)

And I think you mean Lists view. Just try the shortcut keys given above.